# How can I invite friend to test range?

Tags: battlefield-4

I have heard that you can invite a friend to the test range. How can this be done?

I do not see on the battle log a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test Range is an offline component (as stated [here](http://www.battlefield.com/uk/battlefield-4/news/combat-training-in-test-range)) so there is no multiplayer support.

Answer (score 10):

Well Matt's answer is not quite true. While no "official" support, it can be done, if you are playing on PC and are running a server. I ran a Test Range server for a few weeks when the trick first came out but issues with moving people made me cancel it.

If you have a server with RCON access (mine was with Multiplay and their ClanForge panel) enter these commands one line at a time

> maplist.clear
>   maplist.add mp_playground tmp 2
>   maplist.save
>   admin.shutdown

This clear the maplist. Sets the new map (the Test Range). Saves the maplist. Then shuts down the server.

You can then join the server. The first person that joins will be on the US team. The second will be on the CN side and, even though there are spawn points, you will be unable to spawn. You can use the RCON command admin.moveplayer to switch between teams, or a better way is to have your friends as friends in Battlelog. Once one of you joins the server on the US side is to join them from Battlelog as it will always put you in the same squad on the same team.

Here's an instruction video: